# Why can't I find the certificate by store name and hash?

Tags: c#, .net, iis, certificate

In my code I enumerate all local IIS sites and for each site I try to validate the certificate for port 443.

```
using( var sm = new ServerManager() ) {
  foreach( var site in sm.Sites ) {
    foreach( var binding in site.Bindings ) {
       if( binding.EndPoint.Port == 443 ) {
          var thumbprint = binding.CertificateHash;
          var storeName = binding.CertificateStoreName;
          //validation here...
       }
    }
  }
}
```

This code yeilds the `storeName` being `"MY"` and `thumbprint` being some byte array that I convert into a hex representation.

Now the "validation" part works like this:

```
var store = new X509Store("MY");
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
var certs = store.Certificates;
//find and validate my cert
store.Close();
```

and this code yields an empty collection. Yet if I change

```
var store = new X509Store("MY");
```

to

```
var store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
```

then the code yields a collection with two certificates and one of them has the right thumbprint and I can validate it.

Why does it happen that `Binding` returns a certificate store name but I can't find any certificates in the store with that name?

Answer (score 3):

There's a difference between a store *name* and a store *location*.

All of the certificates for IIS are stored in the Local Machine location, rather than one for a specific user account.

This is what the constructor for `X509Store` looks like, that just takes a `StoreLocation`, that your second example is calling:

```
public X509Store(StoreLocation storeLocation) : this("MY", storeLocation)
{
}
```

Which is calling the [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f07btzah.aspx) that takes both a store name *and* a location.

Your first example:

```
var store = new X509Store("MY");
```

Is opening the `MY` store for the [`CurrentUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.storelocation.aspx), not the local machine. So you're looking in the *wrong* store. Switch to using the constructor that takes both a name and a location.

Answer (score 0):

This method will get certificate for you:

```
private X509Certificate2 GetServiceCertificate(String certificateSubjectName, StoreName storeName = StoreName.My, StoreLocation storeLocation = StoreLocation.CurrentUser)
{
    X509Store certificateStore = new X509Store(storeName, storeLocation);
    foreach (X509Certificate2 certificate in certificateStore.Certificates)
    {
        if (certificate.SubjectName.Name == certificateSubjectName)
        {
            return certificate;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Great, except I don't know the certificate subject.